# What gas is released when heating sulphuric acid?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry

I'm doing a chemistry project and am really unsure about the gas released when heating sulphuric acid.

Answer (score 0):

SO3 & H2O would be produced but if you continue heating, the reaction will goes on till you reach a constant boiling point (337 °C) in which an azeotrope is formed